# How do I get a sorted list from a Qualtrics 'Pick, Order and Rank' or 'Rank Order'?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

This question is related to the following: [How do I access the responses from previous questions in Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190723/how-do-i-access-the-responses-from-previous-questions-in-qualtrics).

I have a survey where the first thing the user does is rank a list of up to 50 items using either a 'Pick, Order and Rank' or a 'Rank Order' question.

What I want to do is to pull out the ranked list of items from the survey and then use that list in subsequent questions.

I've had a read through the vague [Question API](https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html#method_getSelectedAnswers_) and it seems like it doesn't offer this functionality.

My last resort is to go through the process of sifting through the HTML to pull out each item and its ranking, and then saving it as Embedded Data. But I was hoping there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the responses from previous questions in Qualtrics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190723/how-do-i-access-the-responses-from-previous-questions-in-qualtrics)