# Pull, manipulate, and send back responses as new questions in Qualtrics using a web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, qualtrics

My question is related to this question already asked: [How do I access the responses from previous questions in Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190723/how-do-i-access-the-responses-from-previous-questions-in-qualtrics/43192279#43192279)

From going through all the Qualtrics responses on StackOverflow, I already know that I need to write a web service script to pull in the choices, either in XML or PHP format, manipulate the rank order, and get Qualtrics to pull them in as an RSS feed. These are all done through the Embedded Data functionality in Qualtrics. My background is in statistical programming (R, Stata and Matlab) and I do not know how to set up a web service script, and there is no one established method, from desktop research.

My question is: How do I set up a quick and dirty web service that does the above, and which platform is the most efficient one for the purpose above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a web service script in a variety of languages - php, python, perl, etc. If you aren't familiar with any of them, I recommend php as the probably the easiest to get started with. The web service script has to be on a web server that you can access with a url (e.g. http://example.com/myscript.php).  The basic structure of web service would be something like:

```
<?php
  foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
     //process input parameters here
  }

  //add main program logic here

  //fill $output array with embedded data fields
  $output = array();
  $output['Field1'] = "Embedded data field value";

  //output as json
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo(json_encode($output)); 
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I think I should be able to work this out now. Do you have a recommendation for a web server service to use for this application? Do you think 000webhost would suffice? Thanks so much for any response.

Comment: I haven't used 000webhost, but I think it would work.