# Qualtrics: Assign 4-digit Unique Participant ID number after enrolling via QR code

Tags: css, qualtrics, longitudinal

This is for longitudinal human subjects biomedical research. The basic flow of the enrollment process is this:

1. Enter clinic & scan QR code OR click email link
2. Read informed consent form and check I consent [survey]
3. Pass study screener question (are you 18 yo) [survey]
4. Contact form - enter your name, phone, email [survey w/ workflow to create XM
   directory from this data]
5. Baseline survey [survey w/ ID number attached]

I have it set up right now that survey 2,3,4 all flow together assuming you meet all the criteria. This study is longitudinal so for every survey I want their ID number attached so we can track changes over time at the person-level. We are also collecting blood samples so I will need their participant ID number on their blood tubes so we know who's who when we process and analyze them. Therefore the nurse will need to know their ID number between steps 4 & 5.

I've seen on the community boards that assigning a random number does not guarantee unique values and that unless you make the number long you might have a duplicate. Can't have that. The numbers must be unique and 4 digits so the clinic staff doesn't get bogged down writing a 10-digit number on a blood tube.

I'd love for this number to be sequential, but beggars can't be choosers.

Any ideas on how to do this?? Here are my thoughts thus far

1. In step 4 (the contact sheet) set a quota larger than the participants I plan to enroll and then save the quota count as embedded data. Then in the workflow where I create the contact directory, save the quota number into an ID number field. DRAWBACK: if multiple people are enrolling at once, Quatrics Customer Service said they can't guarantee that two people won't have the same quote number but couldn't give details about how to define "at the same time". like clicking it at the same milisecond? second? few seconds?
2. Use the Qualtrics generated unique Person ID field, which is very long and alphanumeric and somehow re-code it with.... python magic?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Create a database table of 4-digit codes and use a webservice from the survey flow to assign an unused code.  Then use the assigned code as the External Data Reference when you create the Qualtrics Contact.

Comment: I saw this also on a community forum. I'm not a total bingbong but i've never done anything java/API before. I managed to make a JSON file for a 2 columns table with ID-0001 counting up to ID-6000 and a blank column which I think will fill in as it gets used. but qualtrics web service wants a URL and the JSON file is stored locally on my computer. I'm a bit outta my depths. If you know of any youtube or walk throughs I'd love to see them.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481680/4434072